# Texto infinito com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Seria possível definir usando jquery 3.3.1 um caractere padrão que não pode ser removido a um input?
ex: Um input tem um **@**, e só pode ser adicionado 20 letras e/ou números após esse **@**, mas o **@** não da pra apagar. Tentei definir usando o **value="@"** do html. Mas da pra apagar. Como fazer pra não ser removível?

Comment: Não pode adicionar o @ depois?

Comment: até pode, no servidor php. Mas queria uma restrição front end

Comment: certo. já tentou algo?

Comment: No front end tentei apenas com o atrubuto value, mas da pra remover quando clica no input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, verificando se o primeiro caractere do campo tem o `@` com o evento `oninput`:

```js
campo.oninput = function(){
   if(this.value[0] != "@"){
      this.value = "@"+this.value;
   }
}
```

```html
<input id="campo" type="text" value="@">
```

Se não tiver irá forçar a inserção do caractere no início do campo. O `[0]` pega o primeiro caractere de qualquer string.

Comment: rápido e rasteiro!!

Comment: Obg vovô! rssss

Comment: Uau, surpreendente. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Só uma pergunta, porque quando coloca um caractere antes do @ aparece um @ e outro @ com o que foi digitado?

Comment: @PedroHenrique Boa pergunta. São possibilidades. Vou analisar aqui e já te dou uma resposta.

Comment: Veja assim: https://jsfiddle.net/y9cum4de/

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado.